# What project templates can be used to develop windows 8.1 tablet application?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, windows

If I don't have a need to publish my app to windows app store, what are the possible Visual Studio project templates for windows 8.1 tablets?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All templates are possible. There is no limitations between store apps or side-loaded apps or company store apps.

Answer (score 0):

Hello :) I think that you are never forced to create Windows Application which only way to publish is via Store. It does not depend on the project type.

You can use everything what you have!

-VS2012/2013/2015 -> Visual C# -> Blank App, Grid App, Split App, whatever :) This are only templates.

-VS2012/2013/2015 -> Other Languages -> Javascript -> Whatever you wish!

Or install typescript and develop js application easier.

-VS2013/2015 -> You can install Apache Cordova tools as a part of Visual Studio tools for cross app develepoment in Typescript or pure JS.

-VS2015 -> You can write hybrid app using Xamarin https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn879698%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Just when you are building the app check "NO" when you will be ask for Windows Store publish

[image]

That's it.

Comment: But these project types won't have a designer screen showing the mobile layout. They won't have an option to debug in Simulators. Neither do I know how to publish them to the device after coding.